# Rotating, Moving or Placing Procedural Texture on an Object

Tags: materials, node-editor, procedural

I have modelled an object with procedural material.
I wish that the texture could either be rotated, moved or placed anywhere in the x-y-z axis or, the surface of it.

This is how far I've gone with the model.

[image: Green Apple with Musgrave as base texture]

I've made some nodes for the texture. And, have 2 Musgrave texture nodes for the object. 
I would like to fill the empty or plain surface with the same texture. By either rotating it along the z axis, move it along x or y axis. Or, place it anywhere on the surface along either axis.
What kind of nodes should I do to be able to have control over the texture placement on the surface?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rather than use the Generated output from Texture Coordinates add an Empty to the scene and select it as the Object output. I used this to great affect here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPvYAHc9vCE

Comment: @rob. that looks too complicated for me as newb.
perhaps there's an easier or simpler way in nodes to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I have Sphere with two textures, one red and one blue.
[image]

The Blue texture coordinates are defined by the the Sphere default generated vector input. The Red coordinates are defined by Object. The object is an Empty.

[image]

Now when I rotate the Empty you can see the Red texture following the rotation exactly.
[image]
[image]

I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, rob. now i can see what you meant by using empty.